# processing a nested list to generate graph data

Tags: collections, groovy

Hi I have a list of lists structure like this

```
udbList=[
      [132, 2011-11-28 00:00:00.0, Save Object], 
          [141, 2011-11-29 00:00:00.0, Save Object], 
          [133, 2011-11-29 00:00:00.0, Read Object], 
          [182, 2011-12-01 00:00:00.0, Save Object], 
          [119, 2011-12-02 00:00:00.0, Read Object], 
          [11, 2011-12-03 00:00:00.0, Write Object], 
          [12, 2011-12-04 00:00:00.0, Save Object]
          ]
```

I am creating a dataXML which generate graphs out of this.
The type of graph is a multi - line graph by date where each line stands for the event (last value of the list- save/read/write)

something like this

```
dataXML+="<dataset seriesname='"<event type>"' color='""' lineThickness='2'>"
 udbList.each{
  dataXML += "<set value='"+it[0]+"'/>" //for that event type populate all count values (1st field in the list)
}
```

I have udbList populated, how do I write the logic for forming dataXML

finally for the sample list above I should have a dataXML like this

```
def dataXML = "<graph caption='s' lineThickness='3' rotateNames='1'>" + "
       <categories>
         //Logic to iterate through udbList and insert all dates
        <category name='2011-11-28'/>
        <category name='2011-11-29'/>
        <category name='2011-12-01'/>  
        <category name='2011-12-02'/>
        <category name='2011-12-03'/>
        <category name='2011-12-04'/> 
     </categories>   
    <dataset seriesname='Save Object' color='""' lineThickness='2'>" +
    <set value='132'/>
    <set value='141'/>
    <set value='182'/>
    <set value='0'/>    // 0 because no value for event Save Object on 2011-12-02
    <set value='0'/>    // 0 because no value for event Save Object on 2011-12-03
    <set value='12'/>
    </series>
    <dataset seriesname='Read Object' color='""' lineThickness='2'>"
    <set value='0'/> 
    <set value='133'/>
    <set value='0'/> 
    <set value='119'/>
    <set value='0'/> 
    <set value='0'/> 
    </series>
    <dataset seriesname='Write Object' color='""' lineThickness='2'>"
    <set value='0'/> 
    <set value='0'/> 
    <set value='0'/> 
    <set value='0'/> 
    <set value='11'/>
    <set value='0'/> 
    </series>
</graph>
```

So I need to insert `'<set value='0'/>'` when there is no result for a particular eventtype on a date 
How do I get this dataXML from my list of lists?

**Update:**
If you want to have a 'set' tag in your xml using MarkupBuilder you need to check this MarkupBuilder grails issue [grails issue 5525](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5525)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MarkupBuilder`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html) for this:

```
def udbList = [
    [132, "2011-11-28 00:00:00.0", "Save Object"], 
    [141, "2011-11-29 00:00:00.0", "Save Object"], 
    [133, "2011-11-29 00:00:00.0", "Read Object"], 
    [182, "2011-12-01 00:00:00.0", "Save Object"], 
    [119, "2011-12-02 00:00:00.0", "Read Object"], 
    [11, "2011-12-03 00:00:00.0", "Write Object"], 
    [12, "2011-12-04 00:00:00.0", "Save Object"]
]

// Unique dates. 
def dates = udbList.collect { it[1] }.unique()

def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder()

xml.graph(caption:'s', lineThickness:'3', rotateNames:'1') {
    categories {
        dates.each { date ->
            // Output dates in yyyy-MM-dd format.
            category(name: date.split()[0])
        }
    }
    series {
        // For each event type output a "dataset" tag and "set" tags for each 
        // date.
        ['Save Object', 'Read Object', 'Write Object'].each { type ->
            dataset(seriesname: type, color: '', lineThickness: '2') {
                dates.each { date ->
                    def val = udbList.find { it[1] == date && it[2] == type}
                    set(value: val ? val[0] : 0)                
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

println xml.toString()
```

The output is:

```
<graph caption='s' lineThickness='3' rotateNames='1'>
  <categories>
    <category name='2011-11-28' />
    <category name='2011-11-29' />
    <category name='2011-12-01' />
    <category name='2011-12-02' />
    <category name='2011-12-03' />
    <category name='2011-12-04' />
  </categories>
  <series>
    <dataset seriesname='Save Object' color='' lineThickness='2'>
      <set value='132' />
      <set value='141' />
      <set value='182' />
      <set value='0' />
      <set value='0' />
      <set value='12' />
    </dataset>
    <dataset seriesname='Read Object' color='' lineThickness='2'>
      <set value='0' />
      <set value='133' />
      <set value='0' />
      <set value='0' />
      <set value='119' />
      <set value='0' />
    </dataset>
    <dataset seriesname='Write Object' color='' lineThickness='2'>
      <set value='0' />
      <set value='0' />
      <set value='0' />
      <set value='0' />
      <set value='11' />
      <set value='0' />
    </dataset>
  </series>
</graph>
```

**Update**: This is nearly the same as [Dave Newton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028527/processing-a-nested-list-to-generate-graph-data/9028674#9028674), the only diffrence is that this one takes dates with multiple event types into account.

Comment: one small issue I have is my caption, and some other attributes are retrieved/formed somewhere I insert them into my xml trying to do this: xml.graph(caption:'"+mycaption+"', lineThickness:'3', rotateNames:'1') where def mcaption = 'user dashboard'

Comment: @pri_dev If `mycaption` is a variable, you can interpolate it in a string like `xml.graph(caption:"\"+$mycaption+\"", lineThickness:'3', rotateNames:'1')`. If `mycaption == "Something"`, that would give you the tag `<graph caption='"+Something+"' lineThickness='3' rotateNames='1'>`

Comment: I dont want the ++ surrounding the string... thats the concatenation operator, can i directly use the variable name like above?

Comment: Yes, that should work too. The only gotcha that you should be aware of when working with these dynamic builders is that you cannot name your variables the same as the tag names, because it will result in a naming conflict when building the XML (Groovy will try to invoque the variable as a function, instead of calling the dynamic XML tag method).

Comment: @pri_dev Yeah, the ++ symbols where there because your first comment had them in the string. You can use the variable on its own, or interpolate it inside a string using `"cool interpolation: $myVar!!"` or `"cool interpolation: ${myVar}!!"`. Good luck!

Comment: Hi..I tried the solution.. getting a null pointer exception, difficult to debug..with so many closures and lists.. actually got it... xml is null!!

Comment: I am getting 'no such property xml for the controller' when there is a valid date range selected. when there is no date range , the dataXML gets generated successfully

Answer (score 2):

Roughly (not the most efficient, assuming fake data again, and that it's a date and not a string):

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

l2 = udbList.sort { it[1] }
series = ['Save Object', 'Read Object', 'Write Object']

def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.graph(caption: 's', lineThickness: '3', rotateNames: '1') {
  categories {
    l2.each {
      category(name: "${it[1].format('yyyy-MM-dd')}")
    }
  }

  series.each { s ->
    dataset(seriesname: "${s}", color: '', lineThickness: '2') {
      l2.collect { s == it[2] ? it[0] : 0 }.each {
        set(value: "${it}")
      }
    }
  }
}

println writer.toString()
```

Outputs (assuming your example output didn't mean `</series>`):

```
<graph caption='s' lineThickness='3' rotateNames='1'>
  <categories>
    <category name='2012-01-26' />
    <category name='2012-01-26' />
    <category name='2012-01-26' />
    <category name='2012-01-26' />
    <category name='2012-01-26' />
    <category name='2012-01-26' />
    <category name='2012-01-26' />
  </categories>
  <dataset seriesname='Save Object' color='' lineThickness='2'>
    <set value='182' />
    <set value='0' />
    <set value='141' />
    <set value='132' />
    <set value='0' />
    <set value='0' />
    <set value='12' />
  </dataset>
  <dataset seriesname='Read Object' color='' lineThickness='2'>
    <set value='0' />
    <set value='133' />
    <set value='0' />
    <set value='0' />
    <set value='119' />
    <set value='0' />
    <set value='0' />
  </dataset>
  <dataset seriesname='Write Object' color='' lineThickness='2'>
    <set value='0' />
    <set value='0' />
    <set value='0' />
    <set value='0' />
    <set value='0' />
    <set value='11' />
    <set value='0' />
  </dataset>
</graph>
```

Comment: well I should say thats one of the shortest solutions I can imagine... :) but again, date is a date and I dont really need to use xml type... I can just store the entire content in a string or a def.. as I am not sure the chart generator takes an XML input.. only takes a string..

Comment: may be in the end I an just convert it to a string?

Comment: Also you have hardcoded the series list.. I need it from the main list if possible.. may be something like def series = udbList.collect { it[2] }.unique()

Comment: @pri_dev `toString()` creates a String, as shown. I don't see any reason to use string concats when IMO it's clearer to create actual XML, which is what you said you wanted.